# Filter records between dates with Doctrine2

Tags: symfony, datetime

I've an application based on Symfony2. As Model I work with Doctrine2. I need to filter records by a certain range of dates. I've three entity:

- Food
- MealTag
- Meal

I can record a meal. A meal has OneToMany relationship with MealTag. Food, has OneToMany relationship with MealTag. For each Meal, I can tag some foods. I can keep all food eaten by a user via this query:

```
class FoodRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByQuantityEaten()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('Food');
        $query->select('Food.name, count(mt.food) as counted');
        $query->innerJoin('Food.mealTag', 'mt', 'WITH', 'Food.id = mt.food');
        $query->innerJoin('mt.meal', 'm', 'WITH', 'mt.meal = m.id');
        $query->groupBy('Food.name');
        $query->orderBy('counted', 'DESC');
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

I need to keep only food eaten during this week (last 7 days). I've a field (m.datetime) that corresponds at the datetime of the meal.

How can I filter a datetime range with Doctrine2? This tentative returns

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 211: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'

```
class FoodRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByQuantityEaten()
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('Food');
        $query->select('Food.name, count(mt.food) as counted');
        $query->innerJoin('Food.mealTag', 'mt', 'WITH', 'Food.id = mt.food');
        $query->innerJoin('mt.meal', 'm', 'WITH', 'mt.meal = m.id');
        $query->groupBy('Food.name');
        $query->orderBy('counted', 'DESC');
        $query->where('m.datetime > "'. date('Y-m-d') .'"');
        return $query->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
}
```

> [1/2] QueryException: SELECT Food.name, count(mt.food) as counted, m.datetime FROM Sensorario\MagnaBundle\Entity\Food Food INNER JOIN Food.mealTag mt WITH Food.id = mt.food INNER JOIN mt.meal m WITH mt.meal = m.id WHERE m.datetime > "2014-10-26" GROUP BY Food.name ORDER BY counted DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$query->where('m.datetime > "'. date('Y-m-d') .'"');
```

To:

```
$query->where('m.datetime > :date');
$query->setParameter('date', new \DateTime());
```